# Cancel time-based function from running in a conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, scroll

I have the following code:

```
var w = $(window);
var $navbar = $('.navbar');
var didScroll = false;
w.on('scroll', function(){
    didScroll = true;
});

function AddScrollHeader(pxFromTop) {
    setInterval(function() {
        if ( didScroll ) {
            didScroll = false;
            var scroll = w.scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= pxFromTop) {
                $navbar.addClass('scroll-header');
            } else {
                $navbar.removeClass('scroll-header');
            }

        }
    }, 200);
}

w.on("resize", function(){

    if ( w.width() < 992  ) { 
        didScroll = false;  
        $navbar.addClass('scroll-header');
    } else if ( w.width() > 992  ) {
        AddScrollHeader(150);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}).resize();
```

It applies a class when required to the header across the widths, but for some reason on resize, less than 992 it still uses `AddScrollHeader()` even though its not in the coditional of the if. Does anyone know why this is happening? I've rearranged the `didScroll` and the top scroll function and in so many different places i can't seem to disable the scroll event.

Comment: Once you've called `AddScrollHeader()` once the code you passed to `setInterval()` will continue to run over and over again every 200ms regardless of whether you resize the window smaller. If you resize the window several times to more than 992 then you'll call `AddScrollHeader()` multiple times and thus have multiple calls to `setInterval()`. Do you in fact want to cancel that time-based code if the window is sized to less than 992?

Comment: P.S. Why does resizing to exactly 992 equate to `'mobile'`?

Comment: Ah right. Yeah thats what I'm triyng to achieve. Mobile should be `mobile and tablet`, but I'll take this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you in fact want to cancel that time-based code if the window is sized to less than 992?
>
> *Yeah thats what I'm triyng to achieve.*

When you call the [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) function, it will continue to call the function you pass it over and over until the user leaves the page *or* you explicitly cancel it by calling [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval) and passing in the id that `setInterval()` returned:

```
// start the interval:
var intervalID = setInterval(function() { /* some code */ }, 200);
// at some later point stop the interval:
clearInterval(intervalID);
```

So applying that to your code, add an `intervalID` variable in the outer scope, set it when calling `setInterval()`, and then call `clearInterval()` within the `if` branch of your resize handler:

```
var intervalID;

function AddScrollHeader(pxFromTop) {
    clearInterval(intervalID); // clear to avoid creating multiple concurrent intervals
    intervalID = setInterval(function() {
        if ( didScroll ) {
            didScroll = false;
            $navbar.toggleClass('scroll-header', w.scrollTop() >= pxFromTop);
        }
    }, 200);
}

w.on("resize", function(){    
    if ( w.width() < 992  ) { 
        didScroll = false;
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        $navbar.addClass('scroll-header');
    } else if ( w.width() > 992  ) {
        AddScrollHeader(150);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}).resize();
```

Note that calling `clearInterval()` with an invalid intervalID doesn't cause an error, so there's no need to test whether the interval already exists at that point, but you *do* want to avoid calling `setInterval()` multiple times in a row without having cleared the previous ones - the simplest way is just to clear it immediately before setting it again.

Note that (unrelated to what you asked about) I've simplified the code in the first function: I've replaced the `if`/`else` structure that called either `.addClass()` or `.removeClass()` with a call to [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), which accepts a boolean as a second argument to tell it whether to add or remove the specified class.

Comment: Not having clearInterval(intervalID) in the function itself would have left me stranded for a bit figuring that out. Thanks!

Comment: Yep. Sorry, remembered that at the last minute. (Or, as you can see from the edit history, 7 minutes *after* posting my answer.)

Comment: Do you think its worth me editing the question title, i.e cancel setinterval function in conditional?

Comment: Sure, wouldn't hurt. The current title isn't very clear in that it sounds (to me) like you're talking about code in the else either triggering a scroll event or causing the page to scroll.